# How much does the Earth's center of mass move around?

Tags: geophysics, core

How much does the Earth's center of mass move around relative to the most stationary objects on the surface?

I'm wondering whether the molten outer core has enough asymmetry to move the center of mass any appreciable amount from day to day.

Comment: This question was posted today; you might find it interesting: [If all the world's ice were to melt, would this shift the earth's centre of gravity with consequential effects on sea levels?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/15267/if-all-the-worlds-ice-were-to-melt-would-this-shift-the-earths-centre-of-grav)